# How to Failed to open TCP connection to web.archive.org:443 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "web.archive.org" port 443)

Tags: linux, download, command

I had an error downloading the wayback machine site. When entering the command to download the site from webArchive, the following error appears (Connection refused - connect(2) for "web.archive.org" port 443) was empty and was removed.I used the following command for the download site docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/websites:/websites hartator/wayback-machine-downloader nchealthyschools.org --to 20191124012453 -c 5. Please help to download the site.

[image: 1]

I downloaded a JSON list of the site and tried to extract each link by command wayback_machine_downloader URLS_LINK --exact-url --directory /root/websites/nchealthyschools.org. The same error knocks out

Comment: Please post a [mre] of the program you are writing.

Comment: @stark Hello, Happy New Year!.I used the following command for the download site docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/websites:/websites hartator/wayback-machine-downloader http://www.nchealthyschools.org/ --to 20191124012453 -c 5

Comment: They are rate-limiting access from their old, somewhat abandoned tool.